# 1 way audio only when registering to OpenSIPs in front of Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, kamailio, opensips, openser

Long time Asterisk user but fairly new to OpenSIPs. I have a SIP phone working with audio both directions when registering to and receiving calls directly from Asterisk. The same phone works with 2 way audio if I register to OpenSIPs and receive a call from OpenSIPs but only IF the call originated from somewhere OTHER than our Asterisk server.

Example that works:

Call from PSTN > OpenSIPs > SIP Phone (registered to OpenSIPs)

Call from PSTN > Asterisk > SIP Phone (registered to Asterisk)

Example that does NOT work, one way audio issues:

Call from PSTN > Asterisk > OpenSIPs > SIP Phone (registered to OpenSIPs)

I am trying to offload all our registrations from Asterisk to OpenSIPs but when we pass the call from Asterisk to OpenSIPs the call goes to the phone registered to OpenSIPs but has one way audio.

Don't believe it to be a firewall issue because we have tested while firewalls on both Asterisk and OpenSIPs are off.

Have tested many theories but, I'm at a loss at this point, out of ideas. I thought I would ask the smart folks here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting nat=yes in the sip.conf on Asterisk server under the configuration for the OpenSIPs server.

I noticed that when I tested on a newer version of Asterisk I got better errors in the Asterisk console. I noticed Asterisk was trying to send the RTP to the private LAN IP of the endpoint (my sip phone) instead of the public IP of my internet connection where the phone is located. Not sure why it was trying to do that. I am wondering if OpenSIPs needs to be modified. Was puzzles me is that I have NEVER had to set nat=yes on Asterisk when sending calls to servers with static public IP. In this case I am sending calls to an extension like 456@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx where xxx is the public static IP of my OpenSIPs server so, no NAT involved there. The NAT comes into play when the call is sent to the endpoint which is behind a NAT. Makes no sense to me why I should have to set nat=yes to make this work but, this was an immediate fix. Will research more later, might need a change on the OpenSIPs side instead of nat=yes on the Asterisk side.

Comment: nat=yes is depricated. Use nat=comedia,rport (likly you just need rport)

Comment: This particular Asterisk server is still running 1.8.8.0, not sure rport is available in that version. nat=yes seems to still be supported in this version as far as I can tell. I failed to state the version of Asterisk I was using in my original post, apologies for that. Looks like my options in this version are "yes, no, force_rport, and comedia". Is force_rport the same as rport? Not sure which options to try but still researching and I wanted to thank you and respond.

Comment: Looks like in this version of Asterisk, nat=yes is equivalent to nat=force_rport,comedia so I don't think changing the nat setting in this case will solve my issue. Any other thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention that nat=yes didn't solve all my audio issues. Some SIP clients work perfectly now for all calls, other SIP clients have no audio, all the time and other SIP clients have one way audio on some calls. So, I'm at a loss at this point as to how to resolve this. Not sure if I should be trying to solve this on OpenSIPs now, on Asterisk or both. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Asterisk 1.8 should not be used with internet access. There are alots of known security issues since it was released. Minimum asterisk version is 13.* at this moment(2019). You should read SIP traces and see what where go RTP and which ports it show on both systems.

Comment: I am aware of the risk but we have protections in place and have it secured. Don't want to go into details publicly for obvious reasons but, it's safe. SIP traces, wiresharking etc is where I start going blank. I know how to run SIP debug on Asterisk at the console and can do other things with step by step instructions but, I'm not great at staring at SIP packets and diagnosing things. Thanks for your help though so far.